# Trying to assign value to *this pointer fails

Tags: c++, class, object, this

I got this program in C++ and it works perfectly fine if I put last 2 lines in comment:
`a = b;`
`MyAr c(b);`
I tested it with a method that I deleted it. The problem is with the `*this` pointer I think, when I compile and run the program flashes for a moment and then disappears. Can you please help me? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyAr {
    int *p;
    int len;
    public:
        MyAr();
        MyAr(int a);
        MyAr(const MyAr& ob);
        ~MyAr();

        MyAr& operator=(const MyAr& ox) { *this = ox; }
        int& operator[](int i) { return p[i]; }
        int length();
};

MyAr::MyAr() : p(0), len(0) {}
MyAr::MyAr(int a) : p(new int[a]), len(a) {}
MyAr::MyAr(const MyAr& ob) { *this = ob; }
MyAr::~MyAr() { delete p; }

int MyAr:: length(){
    return len;
}

int main(){

    MyAr a;
    MyAr b(10);
    for(int i=0; i< b.length(); ++i)
        b[i] = i;

    a = b;
    MyAr c(b);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important things you will ever do in c++ is learn to write correct constructors and destructors:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>

class MyAr {
    int *p;
    int len;

public:

    MyAr() : p(nullptr), len(0) {};
    MyAr(int a) : p(new int[a]), len(a) {};

    // because we are overloading the destructor, rule of 3 is required (c++03)

    MyAr(const MyAr& ob)
    : p( nullptr), len(ob.len)
    {
        if (len) {
            assert(ob.p);
            p = new int[len];
            std::memcpy(p, ob.p, len);
        }
    }

    MyAr& operator=(const MyAr& r)
    {
        MyAr tmp(r);
        swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    ~MyAr() {
        // note: delete []
        delete [] p;
    }

    // or rule of 5 (c++11)

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

    MyAr(MyAr&& r)
    : p(r.p)
    , len(r.len)
    {
        r.p = nullptr;
        r.len = 0;
    }

    MyAr& operator=(MyAr&& r)
    {
        auto tmp = MyAr(std::move(r));
        swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

#endif

    void swap(MyAr& other)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(p, other.p);
        swap(len, other.len);

    }

    int& operator[](int i) { return p[i]; }
    int length();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The definition

```
MyAr& MyAr::operator=(const MyAr& ox) { *this = ox; }
```

is recursive, since the assignment `*this = ox` calls the overloaded assignment operator again. So you have infinite recursion (leading to the eventual termination of your program, presumably).

It's the same as calling the following function:

```
void f() { f(); }
```

Or, in English, you've defined the meaning of "assign from value `ox`" to be  "assign from value `ox`", when what you really need to do is to define what it should mean in terms of the constituent structure of your type!

For example:

```
MyAr& MyAr::operator=(const MyAr& ox) {
   delete [] a;
   a = nullptr;
   len = 0;

   return *this;
}
```

(This may not have the semantics you desire; modify to taste.)